# Three.JS translate target

Tags: javascript, three.js

Probably just missing something simple here. I have a spot light pointing behind the camera at a plane geometry, along with some randomly positioned boxes. Just trying to do a simple top down like demo. I translate the camera on WASD, copy the position, set the Y to zero, and have the camera look at that position, then translate the light's target to that position as well. The camera moves fine but the light does not change target. At least from what I can tell.

I create my light & target:

```
this.playerLight = new THREE.SpotLight(0xffffff);
this.playerLight.castShadow = true;
this.playerLight.position.set(0, 40, 0);
this.spotlightTarget = new THREE.Object3D();
this.spotlightTarget.position.set(0, 0, 0);
this.playerLight.target = this.spotlightTarget;
this.playerLight.shadowCameraVisible = true;
this.scene.add(this.playerLight);
```

Then my keydown event handling:

```
window.addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
  var moved = false;
  switch ( event.keyCode ) {
    case 87: // W
      e.preventDefault();
      _this.camera.position.x -= 0.2;
      moved = true;
      break;
    case 65: // A
      e.preventDefault();
      _this.camera.position.z += 0.2;
      moved = true;
      break;
    case 83: // S
      e.preventDefault();
      _this.camera.position.x += 0.2;
      moved = true;
      break;
    case 68: // D
      e.preventDefault();
      _this.camera.position.z -= 0.2;
      moved = true;
      break;
    default:
      return true;
  }

  if (moved) {
    var lookAtPos = _this.camera.position.clone();
    lookAtPos.y = 0;
    _this.camera.lookAt(lookAtPos);
    _this.playerLight.position.x = lookAtPos.x;
    _this.playerLight.position.z = lookAtPos.z;
    _this.spotlightTarget.position.set(lookAtPos.x, lookAtPos.y, lookAtPos.z);
  }
}, false);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using three.js r.69? If so, it is likely https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/5555.

Comment: Yeah i'm using r69. Would the work around then be to add the target to the scene as well?

Comment: Did you try it? Did it work?

Comment: Had to pull down the main library, as I forgot to stage the three.js file in my git repo. Just checked it a moment ago, yes it did work :). Added the `this.spotlightTarget` to the scene as well.

Comment: How you create your light and target appears to be a bit overly complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your spotlight target has been translated, but the spotlight does not follow.

`Spotlight.target` is a property of the light, but it is not part of the scene graph in three.js r.69.

So, unfortunately, `target.matrix` and `target.matrixWorld` are not being updated.

The work-around is to add `spotlight.target` to the scene. Another workaround is to set an object that is already in your scene as the target:

```
spotLight.target = myObject;
```

three.js r.69