# three.js SpotLight orientation (direction) issue

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

Well, here is the problem,

Actually what I try to achieve is to place, at some places, some spotlights in a basic three.js example.

Here is the way I try to set the spotlight target position :

```
var light = new THREE.SpotLight(0xFFFFFF);
light.position.set(0,130,0);
light.target.position.set(200,-130,400);
scene.add(light);
```

The spotlight (light) keeps lighting the point (0,0,0) even if, when I console.log the target.position.(x,y,z) it gives me the right values...

Here is a quick fiddle I did with my full example.

http://jsfiddle.net/1xfno37y/7/

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26727379/three-js-translate-target/26739232#26739232.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to update your `light.target` after changing (eg. setting position):

`light.target.updateMatrixWorld();`

Or just add your `light.target` to the scene:

`scene.add( light.target );`

Three.js r.71

http://jsfiddle.net/1xfno37y/19/

Further reading:  [Critical bug with spotLight.target.position #5555](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/5555)

Comment: Thanks, now I get it! But can you tell me why the "light.target.position.set(x,y,z);" is not working? it just changes the light target's position right? it should do the job...

Comment: What makes you think ```light.target.position.set(x,y,z);``` is not working? Have you seen the updated fiddle?

Comment: Yes, it's working, I just mean that it does not work without "adding target to scene". But, light has a default target right? why is it just needed to add something on the scene if it is already on it... (idk if I'm clear or not...)

Comment: Because ```spotlight.target``` is a property of the light, but it is not part of the scene graph. Therefore ```target.matrix``` and ```target.matrixWorld``` are not being updated. I added the update to the answer.