# Threejs light shadow works only if helper is present

Tags: three.js

In my Threejs application the shows works well only if DirectionalLightHelper is added to the scene.
Without it the shadow is broken.

This is the code:

```
const light2 = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 1);
light2.castShadow = true;
light2.position.set(-3, 4, 2);
light2.target.position.set(-0.5, 4, 1);

this.scene.add(new THREE.DirectionalLightHelper(light2));
this.scene.add(light2);
```

The result is perfect:
[image]

But if I commet you the line

```
// this.scene.add(new THREE.DirectionalLightHelper(light2));
```

The result is broken:
[image]

Anyone have ever seen something like that?
I tought helper was only a helper, not a world changer

Comment: So the question is a duplicate one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved using this line of code:

```
light.target.updateMatrixWorld();
```

Found here: [three.js SpotLight orientation (direction) issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32203806/three-js-spotlight-orientation-direction-issue)